# PXE Boot VirtualBox Mac OS X

Tags: macos, virtualbox, osx-lion, pxe

I'm looking to PXE Boot VirtualBox for MacOS Lion in a way similar to described with VMware Fusion here:
 http://fritshoogland.wordpress.com/2009/12/17/pxe-boot-in-vmware-fusion-using-host-only-adapter/

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: I've tried VBoxManage modifyvm "VM" --nattftpserver1 10.0.2.15
VBoxManage modifyvm "VM" --nattftpfile1 /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.0

Comment: I'm assuming you got it working since you accepted the answer. What did you finally end up doing? The answer suggested a few general possibilities...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem description is much too short - we need more information about your VB setup, the problem you encounter and the VB log.

I do not have your environment, but ensure that :

- [VirtualBox Extension Pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) is installed and use PXE with E1000 network card support.
- Use AMD network adapters in the VM (not Intel) and bridge it to the host adapter.

Without more information, the most I can do is supply some helpful pointers :

[PXE Booting in VirtualBox](http://reboot.pro/9901/)
[VirtualBox PXE Boot or VirtualBox PXE / TFTP](http://kleeschulte.blogspot.fr/2008/07/virtualbox-162-on-mac-os-x-pxe-boot.html)
[[How to] PXE boot Server](http://wl500g.info/showthread.php?17156-How-to-PXE-boot-Server)

Answer (score 0):

As of 2019, VirtualBox reached version 6.0 and the currently accepted answer is not longer valid.

I was able to perform initial PXE booting using the en0 with my iMac but the **kernel never finishes loading**, regardless which network adapter emulation I pick (6 options available):

[image: ss]

Comment: The screenshot is not visible.